# Shortcuts with command line arguments blocked with IE error - These files can't be opened

Tags: windows, command-line, internet-explorer, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

*My local shortcuts (.lnk files) do not execute if the shortcut has any command-line arguments*

- On freshly-installed 64-Bit Windows 8
- Shortcut worked fine on Windows 7 32-Bit
- It depends where the shortcut is executed from, however - **works if launched directly from Windows Explorer, but not if launched from command line (cmd)** or from another file manager called xplorer2
- Example shortcut in the image, but all others that have arguments in the Target behave the same

[image: cmd kaput]
[image: after-exe mess]

#### Tried Solutions which Failed

- Could not find [Unblock in the Properties](http://wsc2013.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/these-files-cant-be-opened-your.html)
- Enable did not help: "The setting I found that was blocking me from opening files on my LAN is [“Launching applications and unsafe files”](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/59048-help-these-files-cant-opened-your-internet.html) ... from Internet Explorer security settings found under your “Tools” –> “Internet Options” –> “Security” tab –> “Local intranet” or “Internet”
- [Reset](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/these-files-cant-be-opened-your-internet-security/7bbe6bc9-d89f-4407-81fa-ea4c24b39aaf) did not help
- Applying the lowest / least secure security settings for the first three security areas did not help either

#### Why are non-Internet shortcuts blocked / how to unblock them?

I'm at my wit's end before getting frustrated over this issue? :)

- Could it be that command line or xplorer2 execution launches them with file:// scheme or something?
- Funnily, the shortcut works if I copy the shortcut under C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

[ For search indexing: Your Internet security settings prevented one or more files from being opened. ]

Comment: Does clicking **Show details** display any useful information? Is `T:` a mapped network drive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable User Account Control (UAC) http://techzend.com/disable-user-account-control-windows-81/
additionally a software that you run may require cmd to "Run as administrator" first (with a right-click).